# VPN hosting in Kubernetes possible?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, networking, vpn

I need a solution to efficiently host many VPN connections. I have a Kubernetes (K8s latest version 1.22) cluster in place, and would love to reuse it as well for VPN hosting. Furthermore, I'm not an expert so far but have the following assumptions from reading through literature and tinkering with my setup:

- I require two types of VPN connections

  - a) connecting my data centre (with the K8s cluster) to another site [IPsec site to site]
  - b) connect to edge devices in the field. [OpenVPN or Wireguard]
- As VPN is not high available, I require redundancy for the site-to-site connections, maybe as well for the edge once.
- The system requires a high level of security as the system is sensitive.
- Bringing on new sites as edge devices with new VPN connections should be “scriptable” and not need to plug in cables into a pfsense!

Es for some site-to-site connections I just need to connect outwards to fetch information, I could package them into Docker container. I tried to prototype this on K8s, but only got as far as to package the VPN with a proxy, which then constantly changes the networking of the Docker host system.

> Does anyone have an idea, if I can separate a Docker container in K8s,
> in the way it could host a VPN endpoint for in- and outgoing traffic?
> If this is not feasible, are there people who have other solutions in
> place which work in a scalable fashion?

Any help or hint would be appreciated!

Comment: Your data center is on prem?

Comment: I have multiple and yes some are on prem as well.

Comment: Have you looked at solutions like Tailscale?  https://tailscale.com/kb/1185/kubernetes/

Comment: I really like tailscale, but it's no solution for me, as I really need individual setups and restrict access depending on the need of the connected site. I need to compartmentalize the network on my end. What do you mean with "like"?

Comment: @OneCricketeer but your question maybe a specifier for my question—do you know if I could run this inside K8s for “two separated” user groups? Meaning the networks are isolated from each other without interfering with the docker host system, just on the pod level?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with networking in Kubernetes, but I believe a NetworkPolicy resource is what you're after. For example, by default you can disallow cross namespace communication. Within a pod, containers can communicate on localhost, and pods can communicate over DNS within a namespace ; I don't think you can disable those two options